# 'MovieViewSet' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to build a project from a Youtube tutorial but I keep getting this error: `` AssertionError: 'MovieViewSet' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method. ``

Here is the `views.py` file

```
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        movies = Movie.objects.all()
        serializer = MovieSerializer(movies, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Also this is the `serializer.py` file:

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'desc', 'year')
```

What am I doing wrong? Because to me it looks like I am using `serializers_class` ...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Clean the .pyc files and try again.

Comment: @Sumithran doesn't work. I also deleted migrations and db.sqlite3

Comment: I mean ```__pycache__```

Comment: @Sumithran yea I meant that too, doesn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return MovieSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        movies = Movie.objects.all()
        serializer = MovieSerializer(movies, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I believe that was a cache issue, let see whether this works.

Comment: I still get this same error, it's so weird. I am just follwing a tutorial :/

Comment: what is your urls.py looking like?

Comment: I'm using drfs [default router](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter), share your urls in the post.

Comment: Yes, I just had to change ```movies``` to ```movie``` because my ```urls.py``` directed to ```movie ```. Maybe you can help me on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599962/django-rest-framework-permission-classes-modelviewset